# sequential numbers with repetition based on adjacent elements of another vector - matlab

Tags: matlab

```
v = [1, 4, 7, 12, 16, 20];
```

I'm trying to create a vector `v2` with sequential numbers, with each number occurring as many times as the amount of elements between two adjacent elements in `v`.

For example, the first two elements in `v` are `1:4`, so it should output `[1,1,1,1]`. The next two are `4:7`, so it should output `[2,2,2]`, etc.

desired output:

```
v2 = 
 [1,1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4, 5,5,5,5]
```

Comment: If there are 4 elements from 1 to 4, then there are also 4 elements from 4 to 7, not 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish what you are looking for using [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) and [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html):

```matlab
d = diff(v);
out = repelem(1:numel(d), d);
```

`diff` gives you the number of values in between each pair of consecutive elements in `v`, and `repelem` repeats the elements of a matrix the number of times given by a second matrix.

The output is as in the OP, except the 1 is repeated only 3 times, because 4-1=3.